# How to encapsulate many Ruby case conditions within a single object?

Tags: ruby

I would like to simplify my code that performs a single action when multiple conditions apply. Here's a simplified example:

```
case button
when 'up', 'upper-right', 'right', 'lower-right', 'down', 'lower-left', 'left', 'upper-left' 
  move_direction(button)
else
  do_something_else
end
```

If I could encapsulate those options into something like a class or a constant, that would be helpful, but I'm not sure how to do that or if it's even possible. How can I encapsulate these conditions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use an array splat.

```
VALID_DIRECTION = %w( upper-left up upper-right left right
  lower-right down lower-left )

case button
when *VALID_DIRECTION
  move_direction(button)
else
  do_something_else
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure what you're looking for, but maybe something like this?

```
class CaseMatchingArray < Array
  def ===(element)
    self.include?(element)
  end
end

direction = CaseMatchingArray.new([
    'up', 'upper-right', 'right', 'lower-right',
    'down', 'lower-left', 'left', 'upper-left'])

case 'up'
when direction
  puts "Yup, it's a direction"
end
```

Remember that the Ruby `case` statement applies the `===` operator, and you can do whatever test you wish by matching against things that implement it. If you remember that `Proc` also implements `===` as a call, you could do:

```
direction = lambda { |x|
  [
    'up', 'upper-right', 'right', 'lower-right',
    'down', 'lower-left', 'left', 'upper-left'
  ].include?(x)
}
```

and have the same result, without defining a class. Or you could even do it in a singleton:

```
direction = [
    'up', 'upper-right', 'right', 'lower-right',
    'down', 'lower-left', 'left', 'upper-left'
]
def direction.===(other)
  self.include?(other)
end
```

EDIT: or what Chuck says :) Although, implementing objects that define `===` is more general, not limited to just membership of arrays.

Comment: You don't need to monkey-patch Array. Just do `when *direction` instead of `when direction`.

Comment: @Chuck, What does `*` do in `when *direction` ??

Comment: @shweta: It's a so-called "splat" operator, which deconstructs arrays. Thus, `when *[1, 2, 3]` is equivalent to `when 1, 2, 3`, and `array.push(*[1, 2, 3])` to `array.push(1, 2, 3)`. It can also be used in function definition to collect arguments into an array: `def foo(arg1, arg2, *args)` when you don't know how many arguments you'll receive (so `foo(1, 2, 3, 4)` will result in `arg1=2, arg2=2, args=[3, 4]`.

Comment: The `CaseMatchingArray` with the `===` was what I was originally looking for, but didn't realize I could use a splat operator.

Answer (score 3):

The solution below isn't particularly sophisticated, but it's arguably more readable than the original case statement.

```
def is_navigatable?(button)
  ['up', 
   'upper-right', 
   'right', 
   'lower-right', 
   'down', 
   'lower-left', 
   'left', 
   'upper-left'
  ].member? button
end

def main_method
  if is_navigatable? button
    move_direction button 
  else
    do_something_else
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I could encapsulate those options into something like a class or a constant, that would be helpful, but I'm not sure how to do that or if it's even possible. How can I encapsulate these conditions?

Why not simply refactor that code to drop the `case-while` condition and simply use `if-else` instead (since you don't seem to be using other options):

```
OPTIONS = 'up', 'upper-right', 'right', 'lower-right', 'down', 'lower-left', 'left', 'upper-left'

if OPTIONS.include? button
  move_direction(button)
else
  do_something_else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way will be using a set

```
require 'set'

def direction?(button)
  directions = Set[:up, 
                   :'upper-right', 
                   :right, 
                   :'lower-right', 
                   :down, 
                   :'lower-left', 
                   :left, 
                   :'upper-left']
  directions.include?(button)
end

button = 'up'
puts direction?(button.to_sym) #true
```

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, you can also do this:

```
case button
when "up", "down", /\A(?:upper-|lower-|)(?:right|left)\z/
  move_direction(button)
else
  do_something_else
end
```